# Insert distinct record into table with foreign key using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

These are my model and I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach.

```
public class Respondent
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RespondentId { get; set; }
        public User Requester { get; set; }

        public User Provider { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class User: IUser
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int UPI { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this is relationship of both generated tables.

What I want is If user exists in User table then don't create another entry of user.

Issue is when I add a new provider (of type user), every time it creates a new entry in user even if the user exists; what I want is to add a reference of that user in respondent table.

```
private Context db = new Context();

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRespondent(Respondent respondent)
{
        var TempProvidersList = respondent.Providers.ToList();

        try
        {
            var requester = db.Users.Single(s => s.UserId == respondent.Requester.UserId);
            requester.IsPublic = false;
            var providerIds = respondent.Providers.Select(x => x.UPI).ToList();

            foreach (var providerId in providerIds)
            {
                if (!db.Respondents.Any(x => x.Requester.UserId == requester.UserId && x.Provider.UPI == providerId))
                {
                    var provider = respondent.Providers.Single(x => x.UPI == providerId);
                    provider.IsPublic = true;

                    db.Respondents.Add(new Respondent() { Requester = requester, Provider = provider, Role = provider.Role });
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = respondent.RespondentId }, respondent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to passing entities that were loaded by a different DbContext and then adding references to those entities in a new DbContext.

This code here doesn't make much sense:

```
var res = db.Respondents
    .Include(user => user.Requester)
    .Include(user => user.Provider)
    .Where(o => o.Requester.UserId == requester.UserId ).ToList();
```

Where you don't use "res" anywhere in the code. You do use "a" which I assume is meant to be the same thing?
Firstly, if you just want to check for the existence of a row, use `Any()`

```
if (!db.Respondents.Any(x => x.Requester.UserId == requester.UserId))
```

Rather than loading all available entities just to check if some exist or not.

The problem area I see is this:

```
tempProvider = TempProvidersList[i];
db.Respondents.Add(new Respondent() { Requester = requester, Provider = tempProvider, Role = TempProvidersList[i].Role });
```

This is setting your provider reference in a new Respondent to a User (provider) that was probably loaded from a different DbContext instance.

To address this, any references you set should be loaded from the current DbContext:

```
var providerIds = respondent.Providers.Select(x => x.UPI).ToList();
var providers = db.Users.Where(x => providerIds.Contains(x.UPI)).ToList();

var requester = db.Users.Single(s => s.UserId == respondent.Requester.UserId);
requester.IsPublic = false;
foreach(var providerId in providerIds)
{
   if (!db.Respondents.Any(x => x.Requester.UserId == requester.UserId)) 
   {
       var provider = providers.Single(x => x.UPI == providerId);
       provider.IsPublic = true;

       db.Respondents.Add(new Respondent() { Requester = requester, Provider = provider, Role = provider.Role });
   }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

I opted to load all applicable providers in one hit based on the IDs rather than one at a time inside the loop. Within the loop I just attempt to retrieve the one matching the ID from the loaded set.

I would wrap this with a try/catch block and handle the exceptions. The possible exceptions that come to mind is when a User isn't found for a ProviderId. (Can users be deleted?)  I did a foreach on the IDs rather than the loaded references because that collection may not have an entity for each ID based on the above condition.  (if only 5 out of 6 IDs load a provider user, the ID collection will have 6 elements but the entity collection would just have 5)

Another point here is use `Single` rather than `FirstOrDefault` where you expect one record. This enforces that rule and will throw an exception if there are more than one, or no matching record. The "OrDefault" variants should only be used if not finding a row is an expected outcome. `FirstOrDefault` will hide issues if more than one match makes it into the DB, and without an "OrderBy" clause you cannot rely on which reference would be returned.

Comment: "respondent" is coming from the client. As far as EF is concerned it is a POCO class, not a tracked entity. Referencing any entity from "TempProvidersList" or it's related classes will be treated as a brand new entity, leading to duplicates being inserted. This is an example why passing entities between client and server is a bad idea. Try the above code out in your method and see if you still get duplicates.

Comment: Can you append your current code as an edit to your original question?

Comment: `var provider = respondent.Providers.Single(x => x.UPI == providerId);` this is still pulling the provider from your passed in respondent.  use the `var providers = db.Users.Where(x => providerIds.Contains(x.UserId)).ToList();' then pull the provider by ID from that collection. That collection comes from the DbContext.

Comment: alternatively `var provider = db.Providers.Single(x => x.UPI == providerId);` would work.. Ideally though it is better to load all providers you will need in one hit if possible. This will run a query each loop iteration.

Comment: I've updated the example above to rename that ID to "UPI" rather than ProviderID which was probably a bit confusing.